# Error ,The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP;

Tags: c#, smtpclient

Appreciating your help to fix this error , i tried all options mentioned in my case with no result.
my code as following ,
i tried using from user@domainname.com ,and using user without domain in NetworkCredential
also tried to use port 25 and 587.

Error:
Error ,The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [AM0PR10CA0008.EURPRD10.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]

Code :

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                                                      | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                                      | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                                                      | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                msg.From= new MailAddress("User@domain.com", "Name");
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(Email, Name));
                string fromPassword = "1234";
                msg.Subject= Subject;
                msg.Body= strMSG;
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Port =  587;
                smtp.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", fromPassword, "domainName");

                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Timeout = 600000;
                smtp.TargetName = "STARTTLS/smtp.office365.com";

                smtp.Send(msg);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your post, as-is, is missing important tags (like the language). However, I've assumed that that is C#. In case it is C#, please read this: https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0005.md

Comment: Please i need your support urgently